# laravel create to database and get the ID

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

This is my code

```
        $input = Input::all();
Admin::create(Input::only('username', 'password', 'mobileNumber', 'firstName', 'lastName'));
```

how to get the ID or the new created admin raw please?

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Model::create()` method returns an instance of the model, so something like this should work :

```
$model = Admin::create(...); // create the model

$id = $model->id; // gets the `id` attribute from the model
```